# os.rename to move a file

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, exe

I am trying to create a program that copies itself into another directory to be used later. It works fine on my Windows 7 machine however for some reason I am getting the following error message.

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

I have complied it to an executable using `py2exe`. Anyway here is my code:

```
home = os.path.expanduser("~")
installPath = home + "\Logs"
copyPath = installPath + "\Keylogger.exe"

def installExe(copyPath):
    if not os.path.exists(copyPath):
        path = os.getcwd()
        path = os.path.join(path, "Keylogger.exe")
        os.rename(path, copyPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print copyPath and check manually if it exists - does it look reasonable?
Those backslashes in e.g. `"\Keys"` and `"\Keylogger.exe"` are the problem they are called escape sequences in python string syntax, so with the following character turn into a single character. For more info see docs e.g. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

The correct and robust way to create paths is to use os.path.join():

```
home = os.path.expanduser("~")
installPath = os.path.join( home, "Logs" )
copyPath = os.path.join( installPath, "Keylogger.exe" )
```

Comment: `os.path.join` is preferred, but `'\K'` is not a problem. There is no `\K` escape, so Python preserves it in the string literal as if it were written `'\\K'`. The problem is probably that the current working directory is not where `Keylogger.exe` exists. `sys.executable` should be the absolute path to the frozen executable.

Comment: `installExe` also needs to handle the case where `Keylogger.exe` isn't located on the target volume. Python doesn't specify `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` when it calls `MoveFileEx`, so `os.rename` will fail in the cross-volume case.